# Full calendar google integration

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

i want to integrate full calendar with my public google calendar

i did everything correctly 
the calendar show up but it does not retrieve any info from the google calendar 
and in the google project the number of requests are 0
help me find the problem please

here is my code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css"/>


<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDsSKWeApvsm8aSRDvUdTv2fTVTL272GMM',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'bk2cp46c4jr179p79j9qo98f2g@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div  id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to execute your code I get this message:

`Google Calendar API: Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.`
Tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wyu757pr/1/

There follow the steps of this page:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

So it seems you have an API key. Enable your calendar to for the Calendar API.

`3. Find "Calendar API" in the list and turn it ON.` <--- I guess that's your problem.

and don't forget to
`Make your Google Calendar public`.

Quotes taken from http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/.

Comment: thank you so much 
i really surprised how i did not read this
and you got exacly my problem 
Find "Calendar API" in the list and turn it ON

Comment: i did same things but no event is display in google or my full calender ..... what i heve to do ????